# How can I make my flexbox layout take 100% vertical space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I tell a flexbox layout row consume the remaining vertical space in a browser window?

I have a 3-row flexbox layout. The first two rows are fixed height, but the 3rd is dynamic and I would like it to grow to the full height of the browser.

[image]

I have another flexbox in row-3 which creates a set of columns. To properly adjust elements within these columns I need them to understand the full height of the browser -- for things like background color and item alignments at the base. The major layout would ultimately resemble this:

[image]

```css
.vwrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    //height: 1000px;
}
.vwrapper #row1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.vwrapper #row2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.vwrapper #row3 {
    background-color: green;
    flex 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
}
.vwrapper #row3 #col1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex 0 0 240px;
}
.vwrapper #row3 #col2 {
    background-color: orange;
    flex 1 1;
}
.vwrapper #row3 #col3 {
    background-color: purple;
    flex 0 0 240px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="vwrapper">
        <div id="row1">
            this is the header
        </div>
        <div id="row2">
            this is the second line
        </div>
        <div id="row3">
            <div id="col1">
                col1
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                col2
            </div>
            <div id="col3">
                col3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I've tried adding a `height` attribute, which does work when I set it to a hard number but not when I set it to `100%`. I understand `height: 100%` isn't working, because the content isn't filling the browser window, but can I replicate the idea using the flexbox layout?

Comment: Upvote for the visuals, how did you make em?

Comment: OmniGraffle, and Pixelmator for touchups.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You should set `height` of `html, body, .wrapper` to `100%` (in order to inherit full height) and then just set a `flex` value greater than `1` to `.row3` and not on the others.

```css
.wrapper, html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#row1 {
    background-color: red;
}
#row2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
#row3 {
    background-color: green;
    flex:2;
    display: flex;
}
#col1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: 0 0 240px;
    min-height: 100%;/* chrome needed it a question time , not anymore */
}
#col2 {
    background-color: orange;
    flex: 1 1;
    min-height: 100%;/* chrome needed it a question time , not anymore */
}
#col3 {
    background-color: purple;
    flex: 0 0 240px;
    min-height: 100%;/* chrome needed it a question time , not anymore */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="row1">this is the header</div>
    <div id="row2">this is the second line</div>
    <div id="row3">
        <div id="col1">col1</div>
        <div id="col2">col2</div>
        <div id="col3">col3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NWxZzMy)**

---

EDIT, as mention by @Basj , the code can be shorten . We can also nowdays use grid widely implemented : Below an example with grid for the visitors :

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: orange;
    grid-template-columns: 240px 1fr 240px;
}

[id^=row]{ grid-column: 1/-1 }

#row1 { background-color: red; }
#row2 { background-color: blue; }
#row3 { background-color: green; }
#col1 { background-color: yellow; }
#col3 { background-color: purple; }
```

```html
<div id="row1">this is the header</div>
<div id="row2">this is the second line</div>
<div id="col1">col1</div>
<div id="col2">col2</div>
<div id="col3">col3</div>
```

Comment: Any way to do this while also having the content divs expand to fill their contents? [Forked your example here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lhhh3wde/).

Comment: @iameli , use min-height for chrome instead height http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lhhh3wde/1/

Comment: The JSFiddle is brokened

Comment: Here is the working codepen demo: https://codepen.io/mprinc/pen/JjGQvae and explanation in the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63174085/257561

Comment: fiddle replaced by a codepen that should not vanish, it's a copy of the snippet . **Note** that min-height is not needed anymore in today's chrome version.

Comment: Setting 100% to body, html and the container after that and so on definitely works.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus If you put content in `col2` that overflows the screen height and you scroll down, the columns are not growing. Can you fix that somehow?

Comment: @Toxiro Sounds like that's a new question that you should post.

Comment: Great! Here is a slightly simplified version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261320/1422096

Comment: @Basj okay, you only removed the OP's wrapper and obsolete CSS for chrome (notified by comments :) ) Also, grid should also be proposed to make a shorter CSS without the wrapper https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRxdYwP

Comment: Yes @G-Cyrillus, it was a minimal modification - full credit to you for the solution :)

Comment: @Basj its fine with me , i like better the grid display for main and complex layouts that now works everywhere .I do not dislike, flex, and float, which are  efficient for their jobs ;) (nor column CSS or table display) We do have a really good bunch of tools for layouts nowdays.

Answer (score 27):

set the wrapper to height 100%

```
.vwrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;

  height: 100%;
}
```

and set the 3rd row to flex-grow

```
#row3 {
   background-color: green;
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   display: flex;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L4d7M/)

Comment: In my case html, body, .wrapper { height : 100%; } is working. not only wrapper working.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is very good, but I noticed the `wrapper` was not needed, as well as a few other CSS rules. Here is a minimal version:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin: 0; }
#row1 { background-color: red; }
#row2 { background-color: blue; }
#row3 { background-color: green; flex: 2; display: flex; }
#col1 { background-color: yellow; flex: 0 0 240px; }
#col2 { background-color: orange; flex: 1 1; }
#col3 { background-color: purple; flex: 0 0 240px; }
```

```html
<div id="row1">this is the header</div>
<div id="row2">this is the second line</div>
<div id="row3">
    <div id="col1">col1</div>
    <div id="col2">col2</div>
    <div id="col3">col3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To make it shorter you can even use the grid display nowdays ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRxdYwP

Answer (score 5):

Let me show you another way that works 100%. I will also add some padding for the example.

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "flex-pad-x">
    <div class = "flex-pad-y">
      <div class = "flex-pad-y">
        <div class = "flex-grow-y">
         Content Centered
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

  .flex-pad-x {
    padding: 0px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }

  .flex-pad-y {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .flex-grow-y {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
   }
```

As you can see we can achieve this with a few wrappers for control while utilising the flex-grow & flex-direction attribute.

1: When the parent "flex-direction" is a "row", its child "flex-grow" works horizontally. 
2: When the parent "flex-direction" is "columns", its child "flex-grow" works vertically.

Hope this helps

Daniel

Comment: `div` overkill.

Comment: You can remove one of your `flex-pad-y` :)

Comment: Nice..!   This is the only example which managed to make my "content" <div> (in between my header and footer) fill the entire screen height.  All the other examples seem to ignore the "height:100%" attribute.

Comment: It is a cool solutions. I know John says above DIV overkill, but I do not agree. You need the four divs to utilise flex grow both horizontally and vertically (Vertically been the important one!). Glad I could help !
Having the four DIVs gives you a lot of flexibility. Once you start trying to remove DIVs , that flexibility starts to wither !