# 3 rows, 100% height layout, with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to know: is it possible to build a 3 rows layout, 100% height, with flexbox?

```
<header> The header content goes here. </header>
<div class="content"> The main content goes here. </div>
<footer> The footer content goes here. </footer>
```

fixed-height header and footer, while content the liquid part.

I mean, something like this but without absolute positioning:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 64px;
  bottom: 64px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>The header content goes here.</header>

<div class="content">The main content goes here.</div>

<footer>The footer content goes here.</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BMxzn/

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DomeTune/5qqw1kzy/1/)

Comment: @Michael_B Ok thank you, I added my own answer along with proper docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add my own accepted answer here, because it addresses other issues as well.

I noted that the usually suggested code has a problem with Android prior to 4.4.4. By better indagating **[> this](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)** and **[> this](https://github.com/philipwalton/solved-by-flexbox/blob/master/assets/css/components/site.css)** I found out that the problem is **[> this](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#1-minimum-content-sizing-of-flex-items-not-honored)**, even if Android is not mentioned on the affected browsers list. So, my solution was to add flex-shrink: 0 to the content:

```
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content{
  flex: 1 0 auto; // flex-shrink:0 > android 4.4.2 fix (and some other browsers too)
}
```

It's also good to assign some kind of flex property to header and footer. I noticed on Android 442 that otherwise the bg color was gone:

```
.main-header,
.main-footer{
    flex: none; // or flex something.
}
```

Also please note that I'm using **Autoprefixer**. Otherwise, you should not use the shortcut on main-content (**IE shit-fix**):

```
.main-content{
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-basis:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;     /* this is the key; consumes all available height */
  background: blue;
}
header {
  height: 64px;
  background: red;
}
footer {
  height: 64px;
  background: green;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>The header content goes here.</header>
<div class="content">The main content goes here.</div>
<footer>The footer content goes here.</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to these question : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090136/how-can-i-make-my-flexbox-layout-take-100-vertical-space/23090449)

You need only 3 lines of code:

```
display:flex;
flex-flow:column;
height:/* whatever height needed */
```

and then `flex:1;` to the container that needs to fill remaining space

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;/* if you relay on flex, then vh is also understood */
}
body>* {
  padding: 1em;
}
header {
  background: red;
}
footer {
  background: green;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  /* optionnal if you want to keep footer at screen 
  overflow:auto; */
}
```

```html
<header>The header <b>of any height</b> content goes here.</header>

<div class="content">The main content goes here.</div>

<footer>The footer <b>of any height</b> content goes here.</footer>
```

there is no need to set heights to footer or header , but you might add `overflow:auto` to the main container.

Comment: @Stratboy , was it specified in the question ? is it also fine with IE ? :) Can you feed me back about this in android https://jsfiddle.net/10ohr6wy/9/ (flex:1 1 auto;) needed by IE

Comment: since the question was blocked I coudn't add an answer by myself thus I created another question. Anyway, my answer on the other thread is better because it addresses android issues. It's all documentated on the external links I posted with the answer, so you can refer to those.
wrote the comment above only to inform future people, so nothing personal. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Stratboy , okay, i did not see that other question where android was involved :) . Did you give a look at the fiddle i linked earlier about how it behaved in android (about another question here on overflow, i was just  wondering if the IE fix was also fine for android ... or buggy)

Comment: Mmm I don't understand really much sorry. But anyway, the android fix seems to be the same as the IE's one.