# Give flex row content 100% percent height of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with row layout with three containers.  The container on the right has the main content, and I want the left container to grow in height to match.

If I set the container's `align-items` to `stretch` it does what I want.  However, I cannot use `stretch` due to circumstances outside of my control.

The only real options I have are `center` and `flex-start`.  However, percentage heights for `.left` and `.mid` appear to be completely ignored with these `align-items` settings.

Is there any way to get the left container to grow with the parent's height other than switching to `align-items: stretch`?

```css
.container {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
  
.left {
  width: 34%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
  
.mid {
  width: 3%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
  
.right {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div>Hello World!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>Right content</div>
    <div>Right content</div>
    <div>Right content</div>
    <div>Right content</div>
    <div>Right content</div>
    <div>Right content</div>
    <div>Right content</div>
    <div>Right content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: without stretch you have the common issue of : % of what ?

Comment: Are you allowed to use stretch on align-self?

Comment: You can try removing `align-items: flex-start;` property from `.container` or add `align-items: normal;` property to `.container` if it fits your requirements.

Comment: removing `align-items` causes it to use stretch/normal, which I can't do (for very complicated reasons) :(

Comment: The reason I'm restricted is that this CSS and DOM is the output of a custom template system that's being developed.  I'm stuck with the options that template system gives me, which right now are just those two alignment options.  I suspect I'll need to get `stretch` added as an alignment option to that system, but if there's a way to make it work without that it will be a lot easier.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090136/how-can-i-make-my-flexbox-layout-take-100-vertical-space

Comment: And do you have the ability to use JavaScript here in this template system? But yes, ultimately you should make sure whoever is building this template system makes it support all of a given CSS module and not just parts of it.

Comment: Like already mentioned, `.left {align-self: stretch}` is the way to go.

Comment: Javascript is generating the DOM from the template, so yes.  But we're trying to avoid using JS to actually do layout (we do that for one other feature and it's a pain).  `align-self` isn't something we can set through the system right now.

It looks like we're just going to have to add a STRETCH alignment option to our templating system, which is what I expected was the case but had hoped there might be a simpler way.