# Aligning the last div to the bottom of a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

**Scenario :**

- I'm creating a pricing comparison table and am having difficulties aligning the last div, `card-vat-fee`, to the bottom of the container.
- I need to do this because the tiers have longer running lists than
  one another, causing the last div isn't aligned with the bottom of
  the container.
- How can I get the last div to align to the bottom of the flexbox?

**Tried Case :**

- Of course, if I set a `min-height: 320px;` on the `card-vat-fee` class it will align the div to the bottom, **however this isn't a responsive solution** and I feel like there is a better approach that uses `flex` properties. Moreover, setting the `card-vat-fee` div to flex-grow, `flex: 1 1 auto`, produces an [unideal solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVkMd.jpg).

**Code :**

```
<div class='pricing__tier'>
 <div class='uni-card-header'>
 </div>
 <div class='uni-card-body'>
   <div class='uni-row-on'>
   </div>
   <div class='uni-row-off'>
   </div>
   <div class='uni-row-on card-vat-fee'>
    <div class='vat-fee-text'>
     Credit card fees and VAT apply. See below for details.
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<style>
    .pricing__tier {
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 0%;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .uni-card-body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
</style>
```

*Pricing Tier*
[image: pricing tier]

Please Suggest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my flexbox layout take 100% vertical space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090136/how-can-i-make-my-flexbox-layout-take-100-vertical-space)

Comment: Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I don't believe that produces the desired fix [updated image](https://imgur.com/a/m8n1gCO)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `margin-top:auto` on the last div.

```css
.pricing__tier {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 25%;
  flex: 1;
  height: 200px; /* for demo purposes */
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.uni-card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.card-vat-fee {
  margin-top: auto; /* push to bottom */
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='pricing__tier'>
  <div class='uni-card-header'>
  </div>
  <div class='uni-card-body'>
    <div class='uni-row-on'>
    </div>
    <div class='uni-row-off'>
    </div>
    <div class='uni-row-on card-vat-fee'>
      <div class='vat-fee-text'>
        Credit card fees and VAT apply. See below for details.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works @Paulie_D...the answer lied in adding `flex: 1;` to `uni-card-body`, coupled with adding `margin-top:auto;` to the last div. Thanks man, +1

Answer (score 0):

plaesa try this one :

```
.uni-card-body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 'for example' 700px;
    }
    .uni-row-on.card-vat-fee{
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Ihope this will help you!

Comment: This is not a responsive solution

Answer (score 0):

```css
.uni-card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: yellow;
  height: 90vh;
}

.uni-row-on.card-vat-fee {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='pricing__tier'>
  <div class='uni-card-header'>
  </div>
  <div class='uni-card-body'>
    <div class='uni-row-on'>
    </div>
    <div class='uni-row-off'>
    </div>
    <div class='uni-row-on card-vat-fee'>
      <div class='vat-fee-text'>
        Credit card fees and VAT apply. See below for details.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've illustrated the thing in the snippet, it'll help.

> Note: Content justification, background and height are for demonstration and not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the response man, this code however, wasn't a responsive solution as the `height` property breaks the container bounds, and that property is required to align the item to the bottom of the container.

Answer (score -1):

1- set the parent div relative position without top & left & right &
    bottom property

2- set the last div position absolute with bottom:0;right:0;left:0;height:36px;

```
<style>
  .pricing__tier {
    position:relative;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 0%;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .pricing__tier>.vat-fee-text {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height:36px;
  }
 </style>
```

Comment: This is actually the closest answer to a solution...will keep exploring @khalidJ-A and report back.

Comment: After trying, the `height` property made this solution non-responsive. I ultimately went with the above suggestion from @Paulie_D

Comment: height property i assumed to display the gray bar. you can use top:92%; instead of the height property anyway I wish you the best luck