# How to set flex column child to go full available height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the following code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is my `CONTENT` not getting full available height (from `HEADER` bottom to the bottom of page) ? How to solve it ?

Comment: The `height: 100%` you are setting takes into account the total height of the parent, which is `.container`, but `.container` only has a height based on its content; try setting `height: 100vh`; in the `.container` class... also, due to the `flex: 1` property in your items, they will expand to use equal amount of space

Comment: But what if I make `.container { height: 100%} `?

Comment: Same issue, the body of the document only uses the total amount of space its children add up; so unless you explicitly state the height it needs (100% of the viewport's height = `100vh`), percentages are calculated based on the parent's dimensions iirc... You can see this by inspecting the element, the `html` element only uses enough space to contain the children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your container is missing an height** , you can use `height:100vh;` to fill window's height.

You can also use % , but you need to inherit a valid value from a parent. In this case, it can be take from html, send to body, and finally used by your container:([example in this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090136/how-can-i-make-my-flexbox-layout-take-100-vertical-space/23090449#23090449))

```
html,body,.container {height:100%;}
```

example with vh

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*or min-height*/      height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  /* flex: 1; not needed */
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  /*height: 100%; not needed */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works very fine!

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting this answer to clear up a few things mentioned in the comments, if it's not appropiate due to the question already having an answer I'll delete this.

By making the changes I proposed, we set the `.container`'s height to `100vh`, to *explicitly* define that it must have the full viewport's height, without this, the `.container` only has the needed height to contain the elements inside of it.

This applies the same to the `body` and `html` elements.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using percentages to define a `height` or `width` require some *reference* to calculate how much space that `%` unit is**; so for example:

- If we set a width of 1000px for `.container`, we can set its children's width to say, 50% and 100% and they will resize accordingly to 500px and 1000px because they have the 1000px reference from their parent.

**EDIT:** As noted by @Temani, this reference is always present for the `width` property, so using percentages for width will never fail, even if we don't specify an explicit width in a parent container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1000px;
}

.header {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

- The same happens with the `height` property; we define a specific
  height for the parent, and the children's height can be set with percentages since now they have a reference.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
}

.header {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 80%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not the answer but got an upvote!

Comment: note that height and width don't behave exactly the same with percentage. Both need a reference (this is clear) but the reference for the width is always there while it's not the case for height. Basically percentage width will likely never fail.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! Will add it to the answer just in case

Answer (score 0):

Its going to depend on what you want to ultimately do the page and how you are going to use the page.

You can set your `.container` full page width & height:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

and then grow/shrink your containers as needed:

```
.header{ flex: 1 }
.content { flex: 2 } // twice as large as header
```

Answer (score 0):

How @ivanS95 says '.container only has a height based on its content'.
Instead, you can do this by setting all parents (html, body) elements to 100% also the .container at 100% too, and changing your flex propierty of .header not allowing it to grow.

Example here:

```
flex: 0 1;
```

https://codepen.io/pen/

This question was very nicely answered before by @Pebbl at:

[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

please check it.