# How to make CSS Grid with fixed header and footer with remainder in middle

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question gets asked a lot, but no one seems to have an answer, other than using JavaScript to calculate the middle row's height using `window.innerHeight`, and .`offsetHeight`.  That's what I am doing already, but I'd like to do it the "right way" using only native CSS Grid.

I am trying to accomplish this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Header (fixed height in px)       |
|------+-------------------+--------|
|      |                   |        |
| Left |      Center       | Right  |
|      |                   |        |
|      |   fill remaining  |        |
|      |       height      |        |
|      |                   |        |
|------+-------------------+--------|
| Footer (fixed height in px)       |
+-----------------------------------+
```

So far, I have the following. But it doesn't work if I change header and footer height to a fixed height.  It only works cleanly when my heights are all "vh" based and all add up to 100vh.

The grid is exactly what I need except for the fixed height header and footer.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content-main">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="center">Center</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content-main {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
    grid-template-areas:
        "hd hd hd"
        "lt cn rt"
        "ft ft ft";
}

.header {
    grid-area: hd;
    height: 10vh;
}

.left {
    grid-area: lt;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 20vw;
}

.center {
    grid-area: cn;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 60vw;
}

.right {
    grid-area: rt;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 20vw;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: ft;
    height: 10vh;
}
```

Comment: [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) seems a more appropriate tech for the layout you want.

Comment: Have you tried something like `height: calc(80vh - your-fixed-header-height - your-fixed-footer-height)`? See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Comment: Use `grid-template-rows : auto 1fr auto` aside `height:100vh` it should do what you look for to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow and demonstrate  my earlier comment :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows   : auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd hd" "lt cn rt" "ft ft ft";
  /* why fr and not vw/vh/% ? -> you can add some gaps */
  gap: 3px;
}

div { /* show them and give them a  min-size ,to match  col or row */
  border: solid 1px;
  min-height: 20vh;
  min-width: 20vw;
}

.header {
  grid-area: hd;
}

.left {
  grid-area: lt;
}

.center {
  grid-area: cn;
}

.right {
  grid-area: rt;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: ft;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="center">Center</div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

min-height instead height can be useful for long contents, so it can push footer down:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows   : auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd hd" "lt cn rt" "ft ft ft";
  /* why fr and not vw/vh/% ? -> you can add some gaps */
  gap: 3px;
}

div { /* show them and give them a  min-size ,to match  col or row */
  border: solid 1px;
  min-height: 20vh;
  min-width: 20vw;
}

.header {
  grid-area: hd;
}

.left {
  grid-area: lt;
}

.center {
  grid-area: cn;
}

.right {
  grid-area: rt;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: ft;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="center">Center and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br></div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

min-height is not what you want?, overflow can avoid content and footer to overlap

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows   : auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd hd" "lt cn rt" "ft ft ft";
  /* why fr and not vw/vh/% ? -> you can add some gaps */
  gap: 3px;
}

div { /* show them and give them a  min-size ,to match  col or row */
  border: solid 1px;
  min-height: 20vh;
  min-width: 20vw;
}

.left,
.center ,
.right {
  overflow:auto;
}
.header {
  grid-area: hd;
}

.left {
  grid-area: lt;
}

.center {
  grid-area: cn;
}

.right {
  grid-area: rt;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: ft;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="center">Center and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br> and lots of lines<br></div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

For flex, as mention in another comment, you can take a look at other answers of mine [Fill remaining vertical space with CSS using display:flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098042/fill-remaining-vertical-space-with-css-using-displayflex/25098486#25098486) or [How can I make my flexbox layout take 100% vertical space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090136/how-can-i-make-my-flexbox-layout-take-100-vertical-space/23090449#23090449)

Comment: Excellent comment.  I've been terribly busy and haven't had a chance to work through all your examples, but I will as soon as I can.  Thanks.  I'm not just "taking your answer and running away..."  ;-)  I think this will def help solve the problem as soon as I can get back to that project.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark your answer as the accepted answer.